# Mybatis 3.2.5 resultmap collection returns only row

Tags: java, collections, mybatis

i'm trying to fetch results for an object, which contains a list in it using mybatis (3.2.5) , spring (3.0.6) enabled ehcache (2.6.5) mybatis-ehcahe (1.0.2)

but it always returns list with 1 row where table contains couple of rows

observed in mybatis debug logging its printing number of rows correctly but actual result not

DEBUG [xxxxxx] selectGroup (BaseJdbcLogger.java:132) - ==>  Preparing:select group_id, member_id, name, status from  group_members where group_id = ?
DEBUG [xxxxxx] selectGroup (BaseJdbcLogger.java:132) - ==> Parameters: 21600(Long)
DEBUG [xxxxxx] selectGroup (BaseJdbcLogger.java:132) - <==      Total: 2

can any one please spot where i'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

here is my config

```
<select id="selectGroup" resultMap="group">
     select group_id, 
            member_id,
        name,
                status
    from  group_members
    where group_id = #{param1}
</select>

<resultMap id="group" type="Group" >
        <id property="id" column="group_id"/>
        <collection property="members" javaType="java.util.ArrayList"    ofType="Member" >
            <id property="id" column="member_id" />
            <result property="name" column="name" />
            <result property="status" column="status" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler" />
        </collection>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Are member_ids different or the same in these two rows which are returned by the query?

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for reply, i found the issue, there was nothing wrong in mybatis but the 'group.getMembers' method is always returning empty list(some how get method implementation changes..may be one of our team wanted it) so the final object is having list with the last row